# JQuery Identifier Name Limitations

Tags: jquery, identifier, limits

I have a button on my html page generated with php:

```
<button type="button" id="KREDI-CEKIM-TALEP-SIL-BUTTON-cYSDLtvqnA6U0z600fPJ4crsIwLLZGrJmLpRW/t/j2NUJH4E0S0+3a4U7xQZFsDQ7+PoFzBahrekLFFS4lsyJw==" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger" data-loading-text="iptal ediliyor..."><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>İptal Et</button>

<script>$('#KREDI-CEKIM-TALEP-SIL-BUTTON-cYSDLtvqnA6U0z600fPJ4crsIwLLZGrJmLpRW/t/j2NUJH4E0S0+3a4U7xQZFsDQ7+PoFzBahrekLFFS4lsyJw==').on('click',function(event){alert(1);KrediCekimTalepSilFunc('cYSDLtvqnA6U0z600fPJ4crsIwLLZGrJmLpRW/t/j2NUJH4E0S0+3a4U7xQZFsDQ7+PoFzBahrekLFFS4lsyJw==');});</script>
```

I'm writing an onclick event but it's generating error message below:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
#KREDI-CEKIM-TALEP-SIL-BUTTON-cYSDLtvqnA6U0z600fPJ4crsIwLLZGrJmLpRW/t/j2NUJH4E0S0+3a4U7xQZFsDQ7+PoFzBahrekLFFS4lsyJw==
```

Error appears when page is loaded, it's not on click.

Comment: why dont you simply givr the button a class name?

Comment: This id is generated based on a string included in database. I must hide it from user.

When user clicks this button ajax post executes and sending this id. PHP page is decodes it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not jQuery, it's [CSS selector syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) that's the issue (because jQuery uses CSS selectors). The `id` value contains characters you [can't use directly in a CSS `id` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). You can either escape those characters, or use `getElementById`:

```
$(document.getElementById('KREDI-CEKIM-TALEP-SIL-BUTTON-cYSDLtvqnA6U0z600fPJ4crsIwLLZGrJmLpRW/t/j2NUJH4E0S0+3a4U7xQZFsDQ7+PoFzBahrekLFFS4lsyJw==')).on('click', function(event){
    alert(1);
    KrediCekimTalepSilFunc('cYSDLtvqnA6U0z600fPJ4crsIwLLZGrJmLpRW/t/j2NUJH4E0S0+3a4U7xQZFsDQ7+PoFzBahrekLFFS4lsyJw==');
});
```

`getElementById` doesn't use CSS selectors, so CSS selector syntax doesn't come into it.

But it would be better, probably, to use an `id` that sticks to the CSS rules. In a comment you've said:

> This id is generated based on a string included in database. I must hide it from user. When user clicks this button ajax post executes and sending this id. PHP page is decodes it again.

In that situation, I'd use a `data-*` attribute, like this:

```
<button type="button" id="my-button" data-key="cYSDLtvqnA6U0z600fPJ4crsIwLLZGrJmLpRW/t/j2NUJH4E0S0+3a4U7xQZFsDQ7+PoFzBahrekLFFS4lsyJw==" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger" data-loading-text="iptal ediliyor..."><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>İptal Et</button>
```

Then

```
$("#my-button").on('click', function(event){
    alert(1);
    KrediCekimTalepSilFunc($(this).attr("data-key"));
});
```

Note how I got the value to pass to `KrediCekimTalepSilFunc` from the `data-key` attribute so it doesn't have to be repeated. If you have several of these, you could use a class on the button, maybe even a delegated selector:

```
$("selector-for-container").on('click', '.delete-button', function(event){
    alert(1);
    KrediCekimTalepSilFunc($(this).attr("data-key"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your professional solution solved my problem perfectly.

I've used document.getElementById('KREDI-CEKIM-TALEP-SIL-BUTTON-'+id) as jquery selector.

Your data-key solution is seems best usage but it adds new code in the script. But it is better. I'll save it future usage.

Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your long id value, there're some symbols used in jquery selector syntax. e.g. `+` means the next sibling(`#a+#b` means selecting #b which is the next sibling of #a). Why not use class or other selectors? Or you can modify your id name. It's weird to use base64 code as id.

Comment: Are there any method escape all special characters completely

Comment: I don't think jquery selector supports escape

Comment: @wander: Yes, they do, because they're CSS selectors, and CSS selectors allow escaping. For instance, `#12` is an invalid CSS selector, but `#\31\32` is perfectly valid for selecting an element with `id="12"` (which is valid; a lot people they they aren't, but they're mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

Better to add a parent for the button and handle your scenario. Below is a simple approach that solves your problem.

```
<div id="ParendID">
<button type="button" id="KREDI-CEKIM-TALEP-SIL-BUTTON-cYSDLtvqnA6U0z600fPJ4crsIwLLZGrJmLpRW/t/j2NUJH4E0S0+3a4U7xQZFsDQ7+PoFzBahrekLFFS4lsyJw==" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger" data-loading-text="iptal ediliyor..."><span class="btn-label"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>İptal Et</button>
</div>

<script>
$('#ParendID button').on('click',function(event){
alert(1);
KrediCekimTalepSilFunc(this);});
</script>
```

Comment: Or just simply give the button a class attribute, or alternatively give the button a sane id

Comment: This id generated Codeigniters encode method based on another string. It must re-decoded again later.